# Get Client Id of a control inside Usercontrol in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a User Control which has a grid, I want to get the grid's client id from javascript,  Is there any way?

Comment: There are three ways to get the ID of a asp control in a javascript. Check this. This may help you http://codedotnets.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-get-id-server-control-javascript.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could print out the clientid to the page into a javascript variable.

```
var userControlID = '<%=userControl.ClientID %>';
```

In your case if you want the id of the grid. Something like this:

```
<asp:UserControl>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var gridID = '<%=myGrid.ClientID%>';
</script>

<asp:GridView id="myGrid" runat="server" >
//content here
</asp:GridView>

</asp:UserControl>
```

This javascript variable will be available in the global context of the page once it has loaded.

Comment: this will give me the client id of a user control, but i want an id of Grid inside that user control.

Comment: Inside the user control. use the code above but replace `userControl.ClientID` replacing `userControl` with the id of your grid. See Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

This way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var id = '<%=gv.ClientID%>';
</script>
...
<asp:GridView id="gv" runat="server" />
...
```

Comment: this will give me the client id of a user control, but i want an id of Grid inside that user control.